Microsoft Bot Framework dialog issue
I am trying to execute a basic dialog example for the Microsoft bot framework, but getting a strange error and am unable to proceed

node index.js

(node:8600) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
(node:8600) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(node:8600) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
const querystring = require('querystring')
const https = require('https')

module.exports = {
  executeSearch: function (query, callback) {
    this.loadData('/search/users?q=' + querystring.escape(query), callback)
  },
  loadProfile: function (username, callback) {
    this.loadData('/users/' + querystring.escape(username), callback)
  },
  loadData: function (path, callback) {
    const options = {
      host: 'api.github.com',
      port: 443,
      path: path,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'gitbot',
      },
    }
    const request = https.request(options, function (response) {
      let data = ''
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk
      })
      response.on('end', function () {
        callback(JSON.parse(data))
      })
    })
    request.end()
  },
}


const builder = require('botbuilder')
const restify = require('restify')
const githubClient = require('./github-client')

const connector = new builder.ChatConnector()
// session
// const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
//   (session) => {
//     session.send('Hello World!')
//   },
// ]).set('storage', new builder.MemoryBotStorage())

//dialog
const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector).set(
  'storage',
  new builder.MemoryBotStorage()
)

const dialog = new builder.IntentDialog()
dialog.matches(/^search/i, [
  function (session, args, next) {
    if (session.message.text.toLowerCase() === 'search') {
      builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Who are you looking for?')
    } else {
      let query = session.message.text.substring(7)
      next({ response: query })
    }
  },
  function (session, result, next) {
    let query = result.response
    if (!query) {
      session.endDialog('Request cancelled')
    } else {
      githubClient.executeSearch(query, function (profiles) {
        let totalCount = profiles.total_count
        if (totalCount === 0) {
          session.endDialog('Sorry, no results found.')
        } else if (totalCount > 10) {
          session.endDialog(
            'More than 10 results were found. Please provide a more restrictive query.'
          )
        } else {
          session.dialogData.property = null
          let usernames = profiles.items.map(function (item) {
            return item.login
          })
          builder.Prompts.choice(
            session,
            'What user do you want to load?',
            usernames
          )
        }
      })
    }
  },
  function (session, result, next) {
    let username = result.response.entity
    githubClient.loadProfile(username, function (profile) {
      let card = new builder.ThumbnailCard(session)
      card.title(profile.login)
      card.images([builder.CardImage.create(session, profile.avatar_url)])
      if (profile.name) {
        card.subtitle(profile.name)
      }
      let text = ''
      if (profile.company) {
        text += profile.company + ' \n'
      }
      if (profile.email) {
        text += profile.email + ' \n'
      }
      if (profile.bio) {
        text += profile.bio
      }
      card.text(text)

      card.tap(new builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, profile.html_url))
      let message = new builder.Message(session).attachments([card])
      session.send(message)
    })
  },
])
bot.dialog('/', dialog)

const server = restify.createServer()
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen())
server.listen(3978)


I don't know if you're still having an issue with this, but it looks like it is related to the https library. It isn't related to BotFramework. Try a different version or updating the package or use a different library to try resolving.
